# Script Task : write 2 classes and access Global variable

Tags: vb.net, ssis

Can i write 2 classes for one Script Task editor in SSIS(2008). I tried to access the global variable like below. I created 2 classes and it doesn't show any compile error, but i couldn't access the global variable in class2 which was assigned as 2 in class, ScriptMain. Please suggest.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Class ScriptMain

   Dts.Variables("var").Value = 2

End Class

Class class2

   Dim var2 As String

   var2 = Dts.Variables("var").Value

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I don't know anything about SSIS, but ...

You can't use Dim statements in the body of a class - they need to be in a method in .net.

There are special methods called constructors (New), that get called when a class is instantiated though, so try

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Class ScriptMain

   public sub new()
       Dts.Variables("var").Value = 2
   end sub

End Class

Class class2

   public function GetGlobal() as string
       Dim var2 As String
       var2 = Dts.Variables("var").Value
       return var2
   end function 

End Class
```

You'd need to do `Dim x as new class2()` somewhere and then you can do a call to `x.GetGlobal()`. Since GetGlobal doesn't make use of any instance state, you could just make it `shared`.

Beyond that, it's not clear as to what you are trying to accomplish with specificity.